# Using Pandas Count number of Cells in Column that is within a given radius

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To set up the question. I have a dataframe containing spots and their x,y positions. I want to iterate over each spot and check all other spots to see if they are within a radius. I then want to count the number of spots within the radius in a new column of the dataframe. I would like to iterate over the index as I have a decent understanding on how that works. I know that I am missing something simple but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me yet. Thank you in advance!

```
radius = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({'spot_id':[1,2,3,4,5],'x_pos':[5,4,10,3,8],'y_pos':[4,10,8,6,3]})

spot_id x_pos y_pos
0   1   5   4
1   2   4   10
2   3   10  8
3   4   3   6
4   5   8   3
```

I then want to get something that looks like this

```
spot_id x_pos y_pos spots_within_radius
0   1   5    4      1
1   2   4    10     0
2   3   10   8      0
3   4   3    6      1
4   5   8    3      0
```

Comment: Can you clarify which kind of distance you're referring to? When I look at the position 5,4, I don't see any other spots within 2 units of distance under a Euclidean distance. (The closest is 3,6, which is 2.8 units away.) Is this a mistake, or are you using Manhattan distance or something like that?

Comment: @NickODell Thank you for pointing that out. You are totally right. I spaced when making that second results dataframe. I am specifically looking for Euclidean distance from the given x,y position of a spot. I will update that dataframe accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it in a vectorized way, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) to compute the distance matrix, `D`, between all the `N` row/position vectors ('x_pos', 'y_pos'). `D` is a `N x N` matrix (`2D numpy.ndarray`) whose entry `(i, j)` is the Euclidean distance between the ith and jth rows/ positions .

Then, check which positions are a distance `= radius` from each other (`D <= radius`), which will give you a boolean matrix. Finally, you can count all the True values row-wise using `sum(axis=0)`. You have to subtract 1 in the end since the former counts the distance between a vector with itself (diagonal entries).

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix 

df = pd.DataFrame({'spot_id':[1,2,3,4,5],'x_pos':[5,4,10,3,8],'y_pos':[4,10,8,6,3]})

radius = 3

pos = df[['x_pos','y_pos']]

df['spots_within_radius'] = (distance_matrix(pos, pos) <= radius).sum(axis=0) - 1
```

**Output**

```
>>> df

   spot_id  x_pos  y_pos  spots_within_radius
0        1      5      4                    1
1        2      4     10                    0
2        3     10      8                    0
3        4      3      6                    1
4        5      8      3                    0
```

---

If you don't want to use `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`, you can compute `D` yourself using numpy's broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

pos = df[['x_pos','y_pos']].to_numpy()

D = np.sum((pos - pos[:, None])**2, axis=-1) ** 0.5

df['spots_within_radius'] = (D <= radius).sum(axis=0) - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [KD Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to answer this kind of question. It's a data structure designed to efficiently search for nearby points, and it's faster than computing a distance matrix. You can use SciKit Learn to implement this.

### The code

Here's how:

```
import sklearn.neighbors
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'spot_id':[1,2,3,4,5],'x_pos':[5,4,10,3,8],'y_pos':[4,10,8,6,3]})


def add_points_in_range_column_kd(df, radius):
    # Get positions as numpy array
    positions = df[['x_pos', 'y_pos']].to_numpy(dtype='float32')
    # Build KD Tree on those positions
    tree = sklearn.neighbors.KDTree(positions)
    # For each position, check how many points are in range.
    # Return a count, and not the actual points.
    return tree.query_radius(positions, r=radius, count_only=True) - 1

df['spots_within_radius'] = add_points_in_range_column_kd(df, 3)
```

### The efficiency argument

Since a distance matrix needs to calculate distance between all points, it has a time complexity of O(N^2). In contrast, the time required to find all of the points inside the KD Tree is proportional to the depth of the tree times the number of points you need to find. On average, this is O(N log N). So this method will be more efficient for a large number of points.

### Benchmarking

Theory is nice, but is it actually faster in practice?

I ran both a KD Tree method, and a distance matrix method, on dataframes of sizes ranging from N=10 to N=3000. I used the timeit module, running both methods in random order for 100 iterations for all point sizes. Here is a graph of the time it takes with each method:

[image: Graph of KD Tree method VS distance matrix]

For small numbers of points, the distance matrix method is faster. After you get 300 points to compare to each other, the KD Tree is faster. Note that this graph has a log axis on both scales.

Full testing details can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nickodell/d7667018908e0c92198cea7e4030779f).

Comment: Very nice comment and analysis! :)  +1

Comment: Thank you for the comment and excellent explanation . I may want to implement this as I am building a system for large data analysis pipeline for image quantification.